# Dynamics CRM 2011 : Report from other base

Tags: dynamics-crm, reportbuilder3.0

I want add report to request from other server (not CRM base). 
My report work in report builder, but It don't work in CRM.

Is it possible? 
How can I specify login to the second base?

My finally goal is display this report on a form. Maybe I can add IFrame to ASP page that load the report.

Thank.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a different database by doing a fully-qualified reference to it from a data set that is based on the CRM data source. Depending on your configuration, you will likely need to give the *NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE* permissions to access the other database/table(s).

Does this help?

Comment: Thank, but I search to access a other SQL Server server. It is the same way?

Comment: You can create a linked server in SQL Server to accomplish that